# Add two columns and update the result with another column in sql while inserting data

Tags: sql, t-sql

How to add two columns and update the result with another column
 in sql while inserting data?

I mean compute the column. i had a datetime column(Start date) and a Month Column which is an integer, i need to extract the month from the datetime column value and update it with Month column. so i just want to compute the columns.

The Output should be like,

```
ID     StartDate     Month
---------------------------
1      20080503       05
2      Null           -1
3      20090601       06
```

Comment: Be more specific, please

Comment: I think you need to provide a bit more info. Table structures, sample data expected result. What have you tried?

Comment: The solution is probably straightforward but we'd need examples of input and required output to be sure

Answer (score 0):

If I got you right - that's what you want

```
insert tablename(StartDate, month)
VALUES(@DateValue, IsNull(DATEPART(month, @DateValue), -1))
```